# Vuejs, passing props to data() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I can't pass props to data() and I don't know why, I have a inline template:

```
<network-index inline-template>
...
<network-list :data="networks"></network-list> 
...
</network-index>
```

In the vue file Index.vue I have this:

```
import NetworkList from './List.vue';

export default{

components : {NetworkList},

data(){
            return {
                networks: []                
            }
        },

created(){          

      this.getNetworList();            

   },

 methods:{

      getNetworList(){

              axios.post('/network/ajax').then(response => {
                    this.networks = response.data.list;                                            
                });  

      }

    }
}
```

And this is the List.vue, here is the problem:

```
<template>      
    <div class="network-list">        
        <div class="row row-list" v-for="(network,index) in items" >
            <network-item :data="network" @deleted="remove(index)"></network-item>            
        </div>
    </div>                                  
</template>

<script>

import NetworkItem from './Item.vue';

    export default{

        props : ['data'],

        components: {NetworkItem},

        data(){
            return {       
                items: this.data
            }
        },
        /*
        mounted(){
            this.items = this.data;
        },
        created(){

            this.items = this.data;
        },*/
        methods:{
            remove(index){                              
                this.items.splice(index,1);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

In the vue console I can see that **data** in props has and array with objects, those are the network list and it is ok, but **items** inside data() is empty. I don't know what is happening.

Comment: try props: ['networks']

Comment: Why don't you just move the ajax request to your NetworkList component?

Comment: I will try that option too. Thanks.

Comment: I just move the ajax request to NetworkList and it is working too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work because at the time the NetworkList component is constructed, data (*networks*) would still be an empty array.

data (*networks*) is eventually filled by the ajax request in `getNetworList()` but this wouldn't be until after the NetworkList component is constructed because of the asynchronous nature of ajax requests.

You'd need a watch set up to update items when data changes.

```
watch: {
   data(val) {
     this.items = val;
   }
}
```